# Lazy Feature Modules architecture migration to NGRX: Angular 8

Tags: angular, ngrx

Hey guys currently i am working in an application with Lazy features modules architecture implemented.
Below you can see how the project is structured.

[image]

Since the application is keep on growing we decided to migrate it to Ngrx.

As is a new pattern for me i am searching for migration guidelines but i can only find ngrx guidelines when creating a project from scratch.

Could you please give me some hints, guidelines,where should i be careful , and possibly some steps summary?

Thanks you.

Comment: For me following the approach [here](https://itnext.io/ngrx-best-practices-for-enterprise-angular-applications-6f00bcdf36d7) has done me wonders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> guidelines

It's possible to lazy load your store but this has caused me more issues than benefits. For example getting a selected project based on the router url and loaded project entities which mixes two feature stores. The following article has provided me a nice way to split up the store whilst allow any part of the application access to store data:

https://itnext.io/ngrx-best-practices-for-enterprise-angular-applications-6f00bcdf36d7

For posterity the application structure looks like:

```
├── app
 │ ├── app-routing.module.ts
 │ ├── app.component.css
 │ ├── app.component.html
 │ ├── app.component.ts
 │ ├── app.module.ts
 │ ├── components
 │ ├── containers
 │ │    └── my-feature
 │ │         ├── my-feature.component.css
 │ │         ├── my-feature.component.html
 │ │         └── my-feature.component.ts
 │ ├── models
 │ │    ├── index.ts
 │ │    └── my-model.ts
 │ │    └── user.ts
 │ ├── root-store
 │ │    ├── index.ts
 │ │    ├── root-store.module.ts
 │ │    ├── selectors.ts
 │ │    ├── state.ts
 │ │    └── my-feature-store
 │ │    |    ├── actions.ts
 │ │    |    ├── effects.ts
 │ │    |    ├── index.ts
 │ │    |    ├── reducer.ts
 │ │    |    ├── selectors.ts
 │ │    |    ├── state.ts
 │ │    |    └── my-feature-store.module.ts
 │ │    └── my-other-feature-store
 │ │         ├── actions.ts
 │ │         ├── effects.ts
 │ │         ├── index.ts
 │ │         ├── reducer.ts
 │ │         ├── selectors.ts
 │ │         ├── state.ts
 │ │         └── my-other-feature-store.module.ts
 │ └── services
 │      └── data.service.ts
 ├── assets
 ├── browserslist
 ├── environments
 │ ├── environment.prod.ts
 │ └── environment.ts
 ├── index.html
 ├── main.ts
 ├── polyfills.ts
 ├── styles.css
 ├── test.ts
 ├── tsconfig.app.json
 ├── tsconfig.spec.json
 └── tslint.json
```

> where should i be careful

Make sure your reducer returns the state unamended for undefined actions. You can test for this. There's no excuse not to test your reducers. These are pure functions and easy to test.

```
import * as fromProjects from './project.reducer'
import * as fromProjectState from './project.state'

describe('ProjectReducer', () => {
  describe('undefined action', () => {
    it('should return the default state', () => {
      const { initialState } = fromProjectState
      const action = {} as any
      const state = fromProjects.reducer(initialState, action)

      expect(state).toBe(initialState)
    })
  })
})
```

Take the time to ensure your actions types are correct - the errors are hard to debug. Due to boilerpate you'll likely copy and paste alot of code here. Again this can be tested.

```
describe('LoadProjectsFail', () => {
  it('should create an action', () => {
    const payload = { message: 'Load Error ' }
    const action = new fromProjects.LoadProjectsFail(payload)
    expect({ ...action }).toEqual({
      type: fromProjects.LOAD_PROJECTS_FAIL,
      payload,
    })
  })
})
```

Keep to the NgRx documentation - there's been a few changes and tutorials are normally at least one version behind. e.g.

```
this.store.pipe(select(projectSelectors.getProjectsLoading))
// versus
this.store.select(projectSelectors.getProjectsLoading)
```

> steps summary

Pretty much the same as the link but a different order:

**Root Store**

1. Write `root-store.module.ts`

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools'
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'
// import { MyFeatureStoreModule } from './my-feature-store/';
// import { MyOtherFeatureStoreModule } from './my-other-feature-store/';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // MyFeatureStoreModule,
    // MyOtherFeatureStoreModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([])
    // Store devtools
    !environment.production
      ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
          name: 'My App',
        })
      : [],
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class RootStoreModule {}
```

Add the following files which will start of pretty much empty:

- `index.ts`

```
    import { RootStoreModule } from './root-store.module'
    import * as RootStoreState from './state'
    import * as RootStoreSelectors from './selectors'
    //export * from './employee'
    //export * from './project'
    //export * from './router'
    export { RootStoreState, RootStoreSelectors, RootStoreModule }
```

- `state.ts`

```
    import { routerState } from './router'
    import { employeeState } from './employee'
    import { projectState } from './project'

    export interface State {
      router: routerState.State
      employees: employeeState.State
      projects: projectState.State
    }
```

- `selectors.ts`

```
    import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store'
    import { Project } from './project/project.model'
    import { routerSelectors } from './router'
    import { projectSelectors } from './project'

    export const getSelectedProject = createSelector(
      projectSelectors.getProjectsEntities,
      routerSelectors.getRouterState,
      (entities, router): Project => {
        return router.state && entities[router.state.params.id]
      }
    )
```

3. Import `RootStoreModule` into `app.module.ts`

**Feature Store**

1. Define your Feature State
2. Define Feature Actions
3. Write your Feature Effects
4. Write your Feature Reducer (Test first if possible)
5. Write your Feature Module
6. Write your `index.ts`, add to root `index.ts`
7. Add Feature State to Root State
8. Declare Feature Module  as part of Root Store module.
9. Define Feature Selectors
10. Define any Root Selectors (mixes feature selectors)

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-feature-store-plus-devtools-router)

Comment: So for each lazy feature module i will have a feature store  and all of them will be defined in the root-store ?

Comment: not quite...I think of your lazy modules and feature store modules as separate. So I might have a lazy admin module when user fills out a form that requires data such as Projects, Employees so each dataset would fit naturally into a feature store module all imported into the root store module